# Intercept spring data jpa annotation @Modifying

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to audit all entity modifications, so I used a class that implements org.hibernate.Interceptor. But the onDelete method does not get called if I delete the entity(or entities) using this method:

`@Modifying
    @Query ("delete from Brand b where b.name= :name")
    public void deleteAllByName(Param("name") String name);`

Is there a way to intercept this kind of queries?

P.S.: Calling the interceptors method before/after every this kind of query is not an option, because there are over 100 cases and probably more will be written.

Thanks,
Tekin.

Comment: Why invent your own and not use something like Hibernate Envers?

Comment: There are a lot of entities (other may be created, by other developers) and I don't want to modify (in this case, annotate) each one. From what I've read about Hibernate Envers, I should modify each entity. Am I wrong?

Comment: So you rather hack/coble together a solution then use a proven well tested solution. The only thing to do is that you need to add a `@Audited` annotation on the classes that need to be monitored. You could even do special auditing on entity relations.

Comment: I agree with you, but this is not an efficient solution for my particular because there are exactly 247 entities now. I want to write a piece of code  in one place so it would be easily maintainable, loosely coupled and work whether or not a new entity is created.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not a good one, but it will do for now: I overriden the method `public String onPrepareStatement(String query)` in the EmptyInterceptor (basic implementation for Interceptor) and checked if the query started with 'insert', 'update' or 'delete'. I needed to know this because I had to  mark an entity as being expired. Still, if anyone has a better solution please tell me.

Thank you.